# FileMerge tool errors

Tags: xcode, tortoisehg, filemerge

I use TortoiseHG with Xcode FileMerge tool. When FileMerge  starts, I see tons of messages  in the Tortoise console. Message is:

```
FileMerge[3956:35879] Couldn't load language spec for '<DVTSourceCodeLanguage:0x600000cbc1b0:'Xcode.SourceCodeLanguage.Swift'>'
```

After this, FileMerge interface freezes for a long time and after that it works very slowly

Device: MacBook Pro 14-inch, 2023, Apple M2 Pro,
OS: Sonoma 14.1 (23B74),
Xcode 15.0.1,
Tortoise 6.5.1

How can I solve this problem ?

Thank you

Comment: I have this exact same error with SnailSVN only my FileMerge crashes. If I have FileMerge open first it will come up, but the base file will be blank so it is useless. I found this https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/101900 from 5 years ago but I can't implement the workaround because I can't write to the Xcode.app directory.